# How to perform an arithmetic action on all the elements of a list in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a very long list of values and I want to divide them all by the same number, is there a way to do this in one command instead of doing this by member:

```
set new_list [list ]
foreach member $list {
    lappend new_list [expr $member / 1E9]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. And always brace your expressions.

```
proc map {lst expr} {
    foreach item $lst { lappend r [expr [string map {%x $item} $expr]] }
    return $r
}

map [list 2.3 4.5 6.7] {%x * %x + 0.5}
map [list ...] {%x / 1e9}
```

might be a solution if you want - but there is nothing builtin for that.

Comment: We're looking at providing something more built-in for 8.6.

Answer (score 3):

Tcllib's [::struct::list](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/struct_list.html) package has a mapping function:

```
package require struct::list
set lst {1 2 3 4 5}
set new [::struct::list mapfor x $lst {expr {$x * $x}}]
# => 1 4 9 16 25
```